# How can I set this bootstrap grid for sm and xs size displays?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid layout for md+ displays which looks like (they are all in one row div):

```
A(col-md-8) | B(col-md-4)
C(col-md-8) | D(col-md-4)
```

For small and extra small displays I'd like to have:

```
B(col-sm-6) | D(col-sm-6)
A(col-sm-12)
C(col-sm-12)
```

Is it possible to do something like this with bootstrap grid system?

Comment: Use for small screens (smaller than 4,5") `col-xs-..`, and for screens between mobile and ipad `col-sm-..`, between ipad and small laptops `col-md-..`, and bigger `col-lg-..`. You can define each grid foreach screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nesting along with `push` `pull` like this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12"> B </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12"> D </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"> A </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-12"> C </div>
           </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/BS5Vuz0XEt

Comment: A far better answer than mine.  This should be accepted.

Comment: @Skelly can you help me by explaining your thought process behind this solution?

Comment: I thought "mobile first", so I made the xs/sm layout the "inner" columns, and then nested this inside the desired md/lg "outer" layout.. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

### Grid Classes

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

- xs (for phones)
- sm (for tablets)
- md (for laptops)
- lg (for desktops)

The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

*Tip: Each class scales up, so if you wish to set the same widths for `xs` and `sm`, you only need to specify `xs`.*

---

### Grid System Rules

Some Bootstrap grid system rules:

Rows must be placed within a `.container (fixed-width)` or `.container-fluid (full-width)` for proper alignment and padding
Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows
Predefined classes like `.row` and `.col-sm-4` are available for quickly making grid layouts
Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows
Grid columns are created by specifying the number of 12 available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-sm-4`.

---

### Examples

- [Stacked-to-horizontal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_stacked_to_horizontal.asp)
- [Small devices](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_small.asp)
- [Medium devices](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp)
- [Large devices](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_large.asp)

([Source](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a little be of redundant code.

```
<div class="row"">
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8">COL A (MD and LG only)</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">COL B</div>
    <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-12">COL A (XS and SM only)</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">COL C</div>
    <div class="col-cs-6 col-md-4">COL D</div>
</div>
```

You can get the B/D ordering the way you want without anything tricky, but that gets you:

```
A
B D
C
```

In order to get A where you like on XS/SM devices, you need to have that column twice and mark it hidden for certain sizes.  Also note that I am only using -XS and -MD for the column widths.  XS covers SM when no separate SM is specified, just like MD covers LG as well.  The responsive utilities hidden-xx and visible-xx, however, need to be specified for each size.

Hope that helps.  I know it isn't optimal.